# Program to calculate the sum of terms? c++

Tags: c++

So im trying to write a program that will calculate the sum of terms but each term is 3 times the previous term minus the second previous term so it looks like this `0, 1, 3, 8, 21, 55` and so on. For example if the user wants 4 terms then the program should output 21. The part im having problems with is setting up the variables to store the previous number and the second previous number. This is what i have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int num;
  int last;
  int last2;
  int current;

  cout << "Number of terms to be shown: ";
  cin >> num;

  for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
    for(int term; term <= i; i++){
      //THIS IS WHERE IM STUCK
    }
  }
}
```

The way i see it is the first for loop will tell the nested for loop how many times to run. In the nested for loop i think is where the math should go (`current = (last * 3) - last2`) while updating the `last` and `last2` variables to keep the term list going. And then outside the loop i would `cout << current` so it would display the term. Like always, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Initialize two first elements (example: last2= 0, last=1),. Then iterate from `i=3` to `numOfTerms`, updating in each cycle the two previous vars. That's mainly what you have planned. The go ahead of it.

Answer (score 3):

There is an Undefined Behavior in your code in:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
    for(int term; term <= i; i++){ // term not initiaized. and the loop is infinte
        //THIS IS WHERE IM STUCK
    }
}
```

You are using `term` without being intialized. Also you are stuck in the inner loop because you should increment `term` not `i` in the inner loop.

So you can make it this way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num; ++i){
    for(int term = 0; term <= i; ++term){
        // now rock here
    }
}
```

Comment: there's no need for nested loops. `3 times the previous term minus the second previous term` only requires accessing two data members.

Comment: @Jeffrey: I was not to find a good algorithm for the OP but instead I only diagnosed his crashing points.

Comment: @Jeffrey would mind telling me how i could do this with just the one for loop? Im new to c++ and just starting learning about loops so maybe your seeing something differently than i am

Answer (score 2):

You would typically remember the last two values, and simply go on computing the next one:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int num;

  cout << "Number of terms to be shown: ";
  cin >> num;

  int p1 = 1;
  int p2 = 0;
  cout << p2 << " " << p1 << " ";
  num -= 2;

  while (num > 0)
  {
      int current = 3 * p1 - p2;
      cout << current << " ";

      p2 = p1;
      p1 = current;
      num--;
   }
}
```

Comment: Note though, that just taking this and handing it out as your homework solution will cost you in the long run. You should pause here and make sure you understand every single line.

Comment: thats what im doing. i always make sure i can replicate it and then try 1 or 2 other variants of the question before doing anything. I have no interest in turning this is in for homework just to pass becuase that would be a waste time and money. I actually want to learn what im being taught and so far it has been going good, this is the second ive stumped.

Answer (score 1):

This is the algorithm as I see it in my head when I read your question:

```
unsigned term(unsigned num) {

    //                  the previous term*3   minus   the second previous term
    if(num > 1) return   term(num - 1) * 3      -        term(num - 2);

    return num; // 0 or 1
}
```

It uses [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) to call itself, which is a great way to visualize what needs to be done for problems like this. The function works *as-is* but only for *small* `num`s, or else you'll get a stack overflow. It's also rather time consuming since it's doing function calls and calculates all terms many, many times.

Comment: Running time issues will kick in long before stack overflow :-)

Comment: @Jeffrey Yeah - it's dead slow. It's more of a visual aid.